# How to set a custom keyboard for a UITextfield programmatically?

Tags: ios, keyboard

I have developed a Custom Keyboard Extension. But I don't know, how to set this custom keyboard programmatically. The user can do it in a textfield with the standard interface keyboard key "". ( Ok, before he have had to configure the system settings) The textfield will get the custom keyboard extension.
But is there a way to do this on behalf of the user?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I've got the same question.

Comment: A good  question because to configure the system settings is strange.